# How to make a click of a few seconds

Tags: java, selenium

First post ... 
I discovered javascript and selenium, I'm trying to make a left click  of a duration of 1 or 2 seconds.
It is easy to make a right click or a double click, but how to make a long click?

Thank you for your support.

Double click is ok :

```
 Actions action = new Actions(driver);
 WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.ID ("Element ID"));
 action. doubleClick (link).perform();
```

Click with executeScript ok:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 js.executeScript("document.querySelector(script).click();",Arguments);
```

At this point I have no track for the long click ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this below option

```
public void loingClick(WebDriver driver,WebElement element, int numberOfSeconds) throws Exception
{
  Actions action = new Actions(driver);
  action.clickAndHold(element).build().perform();
  Thread.sleep(1000*numberOfSeconds);
  action.moveToElement(element).release();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works very well.
I thought clickandHold() started with a "press the button" and ended with "release the button"